# Android bindString not functioning as it should

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to execute an sql statement , but as debug shows the bindString function does nothing and I end up with 
"                INSERT INTO mytable (name1, name2 , name3)(?,?,?);"
The code is really simple, what could go wrong

```
           SQLiteStatement statement = mydb.compileStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (name1, name2 , name3) values (?, ?, ?)");
            statement.clearBindings();
            statement.bindString(1,"one");
            statement.bindString(2,"two");
            statement.bindString(3,"three");
            statement.execute();
```

Comment: Why don't you start binding from 0?

Comment: "as debug shows" and as you have *not* shown.

Comment: the index starts at 1 :) 
Cannot bind argument at index 0 because the index is out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable binding is not text replacement. The `?` are there in the SQL string. Values for variables are bound to the compiled SQL program you cannot see when debugging your Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Apperntly debug doesn't show the bind itself but the bind works nevertheless.